# Failing to install panelr package

Tags: r, panel-data, install.packages

I am failing to read in the panelr package from the library. I used the package utilising its wbm() function on some panel data earlier this year and I have even tried to install it and I get this message: Warning in install.packages :   package ‘panelr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3).

Has the package been removed? Kindly assist on how I can install it or the new version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want a specific version, use the `versions` package

```
install.packages('versions')
```

Then use

```
library(versions)
install.versions('panelr', '0.7.3')
```

If that version is not available in the MRAN repo, check the available versions with

```
available.versions('panelr')
```

If there are no versions available, then it returns an error.  In that case, an option is to download the archived tar file from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/panelr/ and then use `install.packages` to with `source = TRUE`

```
install.packages('path/to/.../...tar.gz', source = TRUE, repos = NULL)
```

Comment: I have followed your suggested steps and it seems it's not working, as I am getting some error message as per below: library(versions)
> install.versions('panelr', '3.6.3')
Error in if (!all(df$available)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In current.version(pkgs) :
  The current version and publication date of panelr could notbe detected

Comment: @hzhou sorry, the version number I showed was a typo.  I copied from your R version instead of the version of the package.  Can you try now

Comment: I have tried with the last version of panelr and getting this error message now: install.versions('panelr', '0.7.3')
Error in download.file(url, file, quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot'

Comment: @hzhou Also, before you try `install.versions`, it may be better to check the versions available in the repo il.e `available.versions('panelr')`  It is possible that the version number in the MRAN repo would be different one.

Comment: @hzhou another option is to download the tar file into local repo from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/panelr/) and then use `install.packages('path/to/tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')`

Comment: Have followed your suggestion and now I'm getting this: Warning: invalid package 'path/to/tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘path/to/tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: @hzhour I meant the path as path where you download your file.  If the tar file is in a specific location, you can either use `file.choose()` to direct to that location or have the  path of that file where it is stored

Comment: may you kindly advise on how I can use the file.choose() function together with this code you initially gave me install.packages('path/to/tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source') as the file is in my downloads. Thanks.

Comment: @hzhou that would be `install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL, type = 'source')`, it would pop up a GUI where you can locate to where the file is stored once you find it, select and enter

Comment: I have done so and now got another error message (not sure how best to deal with this now): ERROR: dependencies 'jtools', 'lmerTest' are not available for package 'panelr'
* removing 'C:/Users/hzhou/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/panelr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/hzhou/Downloads/panelr_0.7.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: @hzhou that is a different error.  It means that you need to download those dependency tar files as well.  YOu may try to install those packages otherwise as well, i.e `install.packages('lmerTest')` and `install.packages('jtools')` before doing the installation of panelr

Comment: @hzhou I can understand your issue as I had gone through the same source of issue while working with a specific R version in prod env.  Only way to fix is to download all the packages that are needed as dependency because the panelr is removed from CRAN and I don't find any github devel page for panelr.

Comment: @hzhou i find one [github](https://github.com/jacob-long/panelr) page, please check if you could install those

Comment: you a star! I just installed those packages and It's all done now and I'm good to go. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your other question: Yes, it seems as it has been [removed](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/panelr/index.html).